# Create EKCalendar

Tags: ios, swift, eventkit, ekcalendar

I'm facing some problems with creating a new calendar inside a Swift program.
This code snippet almost works perfectly:

```swift
func createNewCalendar(withName name: String) {
    let eventStore = EKEventStore()
    let calendar = EKCalendar(for: .event, eventStore: eventStore)
    calendar.title = name
    calendar.cgColor = UIColor.purple.cgColor
    guard let source = eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents?.source else {
        return
    }
    
    calendar.source = source
    try! eventStore.saveCalendar(calendar, commit: true)
}
```

But in some rare cases it fails in the simulator. In this case `eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents` is `nil` the `guard`-command detects this error situation correctly and the method exits without creating a new calendar.

I tried to figure out the right way to handle this situation. Unfortunately I was not able to find a recommendation at the Apple developer section.

So what it the correct code-snippet inside the guard to create a new source for the newly created EKCalendar instance?

Comment: Try checking the `sources` property of your `eventStore`.

Comment: If `eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents?.source` returns `nil` the `sources` property has the length 0, so no alternatives are available

Comment: If `eventStore.sources` is empty, you cannot create a calendar, so just bow out and do nothing. In a way, that's just what you're doing now. So don't worry, be happy.

Answer (score 0):

The default is an optional, so if not, then you can pick some other way.

(Keep in mind, the preference is really about "new events", not where calendars are created.)

If there is one one source, I think you could just create in it, depending on the situation.

If there are several, you could pick, with the obvious risks.

In my mind, the code should be prepared to fail when all sensible options are exhausted.